# How to display a custom dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to open a custom dialog box(including img, input, etc), like [this](http://netbarg.com/) website.

What can I use?

Comment: google `jquery ui dialog` or `jquery.remodal.js`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ui dialog with jquery.

[Ui Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)

This should be all you need